# Python not reading entire email body

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech

I currently have a raspberry pi python script reading and then speaking an email body (TTS). I am having a problem where python is only reading and speaking the first line of the email body. I would like to have the entire email body (multiple lines) read and spoken. Below is the coding that I currently have set up. I have been stuck for a while now and would like your help.

---

```
import imaplib
import email
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def extract_body(payload):
   if isinstance(payload,str):
     return payload
else:
    return '\n'.join([extract_body(part.get_payload()) for part in payload])

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
conn.login("username here", "Password here")
conn.select()
typ, data = conn.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
try:

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, msg_data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        for response_part in msg_data:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                subject=msg['subject']                   
                print(subject)
                payload=msg.get_payload()
                body=extract_body(payload)
                print(body)
        cmd_string = '/home/pi/speech.sh {}.'.format(body)
        os.system(cmd_string)


        typ, response = conn.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Seen)')
finally:
    try:
        conn.close()
    except:
        pass
    conn.logout()
```

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE http://sscce.org/ Your example is too long to be valuable to most readers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try looking at len(msg_data) and len(response_part) to see if there might be more sections hiding in there.